# Как спарсить данные загруженные с iframe?

Tags: javascript, ajax, парсер, iframe

Есть некая форма в `iframe` с результатом, который загружается после загрузки некоего сайта при помощи ajax запроса.

Кто нибудь знает как разобрать с помощью javascript данные, которые там находятся?
Проверка существования блока с одним из классов, которые там есть возвращает `undefined`

Comment: Вы никак не получите доступ к содержимому `iframe`, который тянется с другого сайта, если он сам не предоставляет для этого "API". В этом вся суть `iframe`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если кроссдоменно то никак не сможете.
Если же нет, тогда:

```
$('iframe').contents().find('some-class')
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Закройте тему!!